# Where does the offers sent by providers collect their CPU model and other data from?

Tags: yagna

I'd like to take a look at where the offers collect their data from in regards to stuff like :

```
    "golem.inf.cpu.model": "Stepping 1 Family 6 Model 69",
    "golem.inf.cpu.vendor": "GenuineIntel",
    "golem.inf.cpu.threads": 3,
```

To see if there's any more meaningful data that can be collected rather than `Stepping 1 Family 6 Model 69` for the model as that isn't a unique value and doesn't tell us much about which processor is in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from `ya-runtime-vm` invoked with `offer-template` argument.
Under the hood it uses https://docs.rs/crate/raw-cpuid/8.1.2

See https://github.com/golemfactory/ya-runtime-vm/blob/e5617ef8adc75ab69081dbc06c5c0d6fa9238e98/runtime/src/main.rs#L433-L448

To find out the location of ExeUnit runtimes:

```
$ ya-provider exe-unit list 2>/dev/null | grep runtime-vm
Runtime:       /home/tworec/.local/lib/yagna/plugins/ya-runtime-vm/ya-runtime-vm
```

and then you can check the output manually.
You can see there all detailed CPU capabilities (flags).

```
$ /home/tworec/.local/lib/yagna/plugins/ya-runtime-vm/ya-runtime-vm offer-template | jq .properties
{
  "golem.inf.cpu.capabilities": [
    "sse3",
    "pclmulqdq",
    "dtes64",
    "monitor",
    "dscpl",
    "vmx",
    "smx",
    "eist",
    "tm2",
    "ssse3",
    "fma",
    "cmpxchg16b",
    "pdcm",
    "pcid",
    "sse41",
    "sse42",
    "x2apic",
    "movbe",
    "popcnt",
    "tsc_deadline",
    "aesni",
    "xsave",
    "osxsave",
    "avx",
    "f16c",
    "rdrand",
    "fpu",
    "vme",
    "de",
    "pse",
    "tsc",
    "msr",
    "pae",
    "mce",
    "cx8",
    "apic",
    "sep",
    "mtrr",
    "pge",
    "mca",
    "cmov",
    "pat",
    "pse36",
    "clfsh",
    "ds",
    "acpi",
    "mmx",
    "fxsr",
    "sse",
    "sse2",
    "ss",
    "htt",
    "tm",
    "pbe",
    "fsgsbase",
    "adjust_msr",
    "smep",
    "rep_movsb_stosb",
    "invpcid",
    "deprecate_fpu_cs_ds"
  ],
  "golem.inf.cpu.model": "Stepping 3 Family 6 Model 60",
  "golem.inf.cpu.vendor": "GenuineIntel"
}
```

When it comes to `golem.inf.cpu.threads` it is set separatly by `ya-provider`. By default it is number of logical cores available at the host system - 1. User can change it manually via `ya-provider` CLI. To see currrent setting you can invoke:

```
$ ya-provider profile list
{
  "default": {
    "cpu_threads": 7,
    "mem_gib": 10.597366839647291,
    "storage_gib": 138.55942993164064
  }
}
```